# Introductory Physics Video Courseware Recommendations

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, waves, resource-recommendations, education

I'm looking for something to supplement my Physics II class. Last year I started using [these video lectures](http://www.teach12.com/tgc/courses/course_detail.aspx?cid=1007) to supplement my Calculus class and it helped tremendously.

I also turned to [this educational software](http://www.thinkwell.com/student/product/physics) when I was stuck in Physics I.

I can't seem to turn up anything similar that deals with Physics II.

I'm pretty much looking for something that I can watch repeatedly until it sinks in. Perhaps you know of something?

Comment: Hi Louis Waweru. This seems too broad for a res. recom. questions, so I'm closing it as a duplicate of the main one to guide the reader in the right direction.

Comment: @Qmechanic can it be a duplicate the linked list is not exhaustive?

Comment: This is pragmatically done in such cases. The alternative is to merely close it as _too broad/needs more focus._

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's impossible. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walter Lewin's [lectures (dead link)](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2002/).

I have no idea of the copyright status of the following transcodes on YouTube. So I'll let them worry about it. It was originally MIT OpenCourseware, FWIW. Prof. Lewin has moved much of the original content there, so seems okay for the SE User Agreement.

## Lectures by Walter Lewin: An Introduction a Framework of  Beauty

1.[Introduction | 8.01 Classical Mechanics, Fall 1999](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUdYlQf0_sSsb2tNcA3gtgOt8LGH6tJbr)

2.[Introduction | 8.02 Electricity and Magnetism, Spring 2002](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUdYlQf0_sSsfcNOPSNPQKHDhSjTJATPu)

3.[Introduction | 8.03 Physics III: Vibrations and Waves, Fall 2004](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUYxVwXZbCU&list=PLUdYlQf0_sSsdOhQ_8jfrAGzbGbJ7MXGe)

### CourseWork

1. [8.01 Homework, Exams, Solutions & Lecture Notes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2eT5Gygn8E&list=PLyQSN7X0ro23dQcOQ0gzRxwJCQnVEbC_T)
2. [8.02 Homework, Exams, Solutions & Lecture Notes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7yVUqYXrpo&list=PLyQSN7X0ro20wGb1lQtYBKvCg4evxaPQ5)
3. [8.03 Homework, Exams, Solutions & Lecture Notes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvNYKG9wzD0&list=PLyQSN7X0ro21aOsJf4OYLbtTMvU45k7bS)

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. Dr. Lewin is pretty amusing, too.